# Understanding of Differential one Form [Spivak]

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I am using Spivak Calculus on Manifolds to understand differential form. I understand that a k-form is defined to be the function sending a point to this point paired with an alternating k-tensor. I have confusion of the following discussion:

> If $f :\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, then $Df(p) \in \Lambda^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. By a minor modification we therefore obtain a 1-form $df$, defined by
>   $$ df(p)(v_p) = Df(p) (v).$$

I wonder what does $Df(p)$ means here. Why does the derivative of $f$ at a point $p$ become a 1-tensor instead of a point in $\mathbb{R^n}$? Does the RHS mean $Df(p)\cdot (v)$?

Comment: Technically, $Df(p)$ is a row vector and thus, an element in the dual space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It happens a lot in the Euclidean case that a lot of isomorphisms are used.

Comment: @SvenPistre Thank you! So does the RHS of this formula mean simply the dot product of this row vector and v? Can you explain more on this?

Comment: Well, no. $Df(p)$ is a row vector or a $(1xn)$ matrix. Then $Df(p)(v)$ is the $(1xn)$-matrix $Df(p)$ applied to the vector $v$. Or in other words, $Df(p)(v)$ is the dual pairing between the covector $Df(p)$ and the vector $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a little late to the party, but if you read through Chapter $2$ again, Spivak defined the derivative of a function at a point to be a linear transformation. So, if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$, and if $f$ is differentiable at a point $p \in \mathbb{R^n}$, $Df(p)$ was defined to be a linear transformation $Df(p): \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$. So, $Df(p) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^n}, \mathbb{R}) = \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R^n})$. Hence it is a $1$-tensor on $\mathbb{R^n}$, simply by definition.

So in the equation
\begin{equation}
df(p)(v_p) = Df(p)(v),
\end{equation}
perhaps it might be useful to add another pair of brackts too see how things are being evaluated:
\begin{equation}
\left(df(p) \right)(v_p) = \left( Df(p) \right)(v).
\end{equation}
On the RHS, you are evaluating the  linear transformation $Df(p): \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ at the point $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: What I don't understand is why $Df(p)$ as defined in chapter $2$ belongs in $\lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It's not clear to me that if I switch 2 components of $p$ in $Df(p)$, then I'll get $-Df(p)$

Comment: @Math_Day $Df(p)$ as defined in chapter 2 is a linear transformation $Df(p):\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$. By definition, such a linear transformation is an element of $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*=\bigwedge^1((\Bbb{R}^n)^*)$  (note that Spivak omits the extra $*$, and points out this error in the back of the book)

Comment: By definition, $Df(p)$  is the linear transformation such that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(a+h) - f(a) - Df(p)|}{|h|} = 0$ and why this implies $Df(p) \in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is unclear to me.

Comment: @Math_Day and how does Spivak define $\Lambda^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$? (his notation is incorrect, but ignore this issue for now; I still want you to tell me how he defines it in the book)

Comment: It is the set of all $1$-tensors on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (denote it $w$) such that $w(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_j,...,v_1) = -w(v_1,...,v_j,...,v_i,...,v_1)$ where $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I suppose this equation hold trivially since $w$ has only 1 argument when it is a $1$ tensor.

Comment: @Math_Day yes, in other words, it is just the set of all linear maps $w:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$. Now, $Df(p)$ is precisely such an object!